# Linux usermod user is currently used by process

Tags: linux

So I'm trying to change user502's directory using

```
usermod -d /home/user502home user502
```

When I enter than into the shell (I'm on root user) I get "usermod: user502 is currently used by process 4220" and I know the user isn't logged in or anything, I just made the user.

How do I fix this?

Comment: One route: you can manually mv the directory and manually update the directory path in /etc/passwd

Comment: `ps -fp4220` will tell you what that process is... and `kill 4220` will terminate it...

Comment: Thank you @twalberg

Answer (score 17):

You must kill currently used process first. But this process probably is your SSH connection. So, in this case you need to run this commands on nohup.

```
sudo su
nohup kill 4220; sleep 2; usermod -d /home/user502home user502 &
```

After you can connect to SSH again.

Comment: This works even when you do from remote, i.e., must log in as user x and sudo to root and then rename x to y.

Comment: When you kill this process, the other one runs again.

Comment: This doesn't work because if your process is significant, you can't just kill it. For example username can be used by systemd processes, so once you kill it - you'll be logged out from your system.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when using WSL ubuntu. I fixed it by creating a temp user, setting WSL to launch via that user (ubuntu config --default-user username), logging in as that user, and using usermod there.

Answer (score 0):

An improvement on the top answer: you can use `fuser` to kill processes which are using your home directory without having to track down the pid.

```
sudo su
nohup fuser -k /home/USERHERE; sleep 2; usermod -d /home/USERHERE USERHERE &
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution I use to rename a currently logged-in user which sudoed to become root. The solution also moves home directory.

```
nohup sh -c "pkill -U <user>; sleep 2; usermod -d /home/<new_user> -m -l <new_user> <user>" &
```

Using a separate shell with nohup allows to execute multiple commands.

Answer (score -1):

After some research, this process can be an reoccurring error in Ubuntu and you only need to restart the system and it will go away.

Comment: Ahh, no. That's a bad answer. Try that https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233624/253391

Answer (score -1):

Log in as root, then open terminal and run

> **kill -9 -u [old_username] && username -l [old_username] [new_username]**

After that run

> **adduser [new_username] sudo**

to be able to run sudo commands with the new username.